# Making reference to a VBA recordset via SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

I'd like to make a reference to a recordset via SQL FROM statement. Example.

I have a Recordset called RS. What I want to do is the following, in VBA.

```
SELECT * FROM RS
```

Is there a way?

Comment: While you can't query a recordset using SQL, you can get recordsets based on recordsets using ADO and the MsDataShape OLE DB provider with its `SHAPE` syntax, known as hierarchical recordsets e.g. see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. They are two different languages and environments. In order to use information from one in the other, you either have to use VBA to send data to SQL to process or extract data from SQL to be used by VBA to process. If you wanted to process this using SQL, there are numerous solutions the simplest of which is to populate a table in the database with the contents of your recordset and then use that table in your query.

Comment: Okay, I'll use that one. Thaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of recordset do you have, DAO or ADO?

If you have a populated **ADO** recordset and you need only a subset of it, you can use [RS.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find single rows which match a certain criteria, or [RS.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) to filter out every row which doesn't match a certain criteria.
Be aware that this only works with ADO recordsets, not DAO recordsets!

It' not exactly "Select * from RS", but maybe it helps you.

Comment: DAO, I think. But I need to refer to the recordset as if it were a table or query.

Comment: DAO has a feature that allows you to create a second recordset by filtering an existing recordset, but I can't think what use it is.